# Getting bottom surface of a model

Tags: modeling

I have a model that is made artificially, the model covers a square shaped area. It's something like that if you look in a cross-sectional view:[image]

How can I remove any noise above the bottom surface of the model, leaving the vertices at the bottom that shapes the S-shaped curve? There is a bottom surface in the object, but as the surface is not modeled separately by the computer, I have no clue how to get it.

This is what I want to get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to BSE, take the same object (but has to fit the same object itself, or there will be issues with the intersections) and duplicate and move a bit in the z axis and add a boolean modifier to the target object, and set the source to the duplicated mesh, and apply boolean, good luck...

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, I tried and it worked.

Comment: mark the question as solved pressing in the button...